# Linq List.Select throws null reference exception but List.First doesn't

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I've got a linq query that returns one item.
When I do `myList.Select(p => p.ID)` it throws null reference exception, however, if I do `myList.First().ID` it's fine.
I have already tried `myList.ToList().Select(p => p.ID)` and failed as well.

The most bizarre thing is that it works on another pc...

Any idea?

**Code update**

```
   var test = A2012_DomainDB.GetGadgetDomainsForUser(userID);
   var viewableGadgetIDs = test.Where(p => p != null).Select(p => p.GadgetID); // this line fails 

public static IEnumerable<A2012_Domain_Gadget> GetGadgetDomainsForUser(int userID)
    {
        var db = Database_Factory.EVISION_EMAGINE_DB;
        var viewableDomainIDs = GetDomainsForUser(userID).Select(p => p.DomainID);
        var result = db.A2012_Domain_Gadget.Where(p => viewableDomainIDs.Contains(p.DomainID));
        return result;
    }

  public static List<A2012_Domain> GetDomainsForUser(int userID)
    {
        var db = Database_Factory.EVISION_EMAGINE_DB;
        List<int> viewableIDs = new List<int>();
        List<A2012_Domain> domains = new List<A2012_Domain>();

        viewableIDs.AddRange(db.A2012_Domain_User.Where(p => p.UserID == userID).Select(p => p.DomainID));                        

        viewableIDs.ForEach(i =>
        {
            domains.Add(db.A2012_Domain.Where(p => p.DomainID == i).Single());
        });

        return domains;
    }
```

Comment: There is only **ONE** item in the list

Comment: What are you doing with the resulting `IEnumerable<>`? Perhaps the null ref is occurring somewhere else.

Comment: it's in the very first sentence :)

Comment: @AdamBilinski Which query provider are you using? Is it Linq-to-Objects, Linq-to-Sql or something else?

Comment: @AdamBilinski Fair enough, must've glossed over that. In that case it seems even more likely, assuming this is linq to objects, that the null ref is occurring later on. Can you post the code that shows these lines being used? The two situations aren't equivalent, one returns an `int` the other returns an `IEnumerable<int>` so the consuming code must have also changed. On changing that, you may have solved the exception meaning that the change from `.Select` to `.First` is actually a red herring.

Comment: I'm just setting the result to a variable.

Comment: @AdamBilinski You are going to have a post a sample that demonstrates the problem. On the face of it there are only two points (`myList` and `p`) that can cause the null ref, but that doesn't explain the `.First` behaviour. Obviously this isn't the case, as you seem to imply, which makes your question incomplete.

Comment: How about the fact that I have committed the code, my colleagues updated and the code works fine on their machines??

Comment: @AdamBilinski No idea, a sample application might help me diagnose this for you... my guess-piler isn't working today apparently. Is it possible that this `.Select` command is custom and isn't the standard and expected Linq extension method? Have you tried stepping through and debugging the code to review exactly *what* is null?

Comment: @AdamBilinski `myList.Select(p => p.ID)` and `myList.First().ID` resolve to different types. Is it maybe a type cast using the `as` keyword that is returning `null`? Sometimes the solution is quite simple. Else, the exact line where the exception occurs would help.

Comment: The query on the db in `GetGadgetDomainsForUser` won't actually run until you try to iterate `viewableGadgetIDs` because of deferred execution. A null can occur at pretty much any point in that code when you finally iterate `viewableGadgetIDs`. Although we can rule out `GetDomainsForUser` as this will fully execute its queries on the `GetGadgetDomainsForUser` call.

Comment: What happens if you make GetGadgetDomainsForUser return `result.ToList()` instead of `result`.  Does the exception move?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot really see exactly where this would come from. The `GetGadgetDomainsForUser` query should be deferred until you actually iterate the returned `viewableGadgetIDs`, but you seem to imply the exception occurs when just running that line.

All I can really suggest is to try null guarding all lambda expressions:

```
var result = db.A2012_Domain_Gadget
                 .Where(p => p != null)
                 .Where(p => viewableDomainIDs.Contains(p.DomainID));
```

And:

```
viewableIDs.AddRange(
    db.A2012_Domain_User
        .Where(p => p != null)
        .Where(p => p.UserID == userID)
        .Select(p => p.DomainID));                        

viewableIDs.ForEach(i =>
{
    domains.Add(
        db.A2012_Domain
           .Where(p => p != null)
           .Where(p => p.DomainID == i)
           .Single());
});
```

I'd be most tempted to say the error is coming from here:

```
var result = db.A2012_Domain_Gadget.Where(p => viewableDomainIDs.Contains(p.DomainID));
```

Perhaps the query into the `db` is yielding a null item, which is then used in `p.DomainID` without a null check.

Comment: @AdamBilinski All sorted? Was the issue in `GetGadgetDomainsForUser` in the end? Either way, glad it's sorted for you.